# Your Ruby version is 3.3.0.dev, but your Gemfile specified >= 3.3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a source compiled version of ruby(`ruby 3.3.0dev (2023-02-18T11:34:28Z master cbac0fa4cb)`).
I did a ruby on rails project as it is described [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). I was at step 4.1 but it throwed this error:
`Your Ruby version is 3.3.0.dev, but your Gemfile specified >= 3.3.0`.
but somehow even though

I put

```rb
ruby '>= 3.3.0'
```

into my Gemfile, did a `bundle update` and `gem install bundler` but still throws this error.

Comment: Can you provide screenshots for which you install with versions

Comment: @000723-weict what version?

Comment: Just provide screenshot for understanding .. of error message gemfile ,etc.

Comment: The error for `bundle update` and `bin/rails serveer` is
```
Your Ruby version is 3.3.0.dev, but your Gemfile specified >= 3.3.0
```
and i have https://paste.debian.net/hidden/96bd44b7/ in my gemfile

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**:
Lower the Gemfile ruby requirement. Options include

```
ruby '> 3.2' #or 
ruby '3.3.0.dev' #or
ruby '~> 3.3.a'
```

**Explanation**:

The error is fairly clear:

> Your Ruby version is 3.3.0.dev, but your Gemfile specified >= 3.3.0

```
Gem::Version.new('3.3.0.dev') >= Gem::Version.new('3.3.0')  
#=> false
```

`3.3.0.dev` is considered less than `3.3.0` based on version comparison. (See: [`Gem::Version#<=>`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.0/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Version.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E)

For Example:

```
# This is how Gem::Version#<=> works 

def comp(a,b)
  return 0 if a.send(:_version) == b.send(:_version) || a.canonical_segments == b.canonical_segments

  lhsegments = a.canonical_segments
  rhsegments = b.canonical_segments

  lhsize = lhsegments.size
  rhsize = rhsegments.size
  limit  = (lhsize > rhsize ? lhsize : rhsize) - 1

  i = 0

  while i <= limit
    lhs, rhs = lhsegments[i] || 0, rhsegments[i] || 0
    i += 1

    next      if lhs == rhs
    return -1 if String  === lhs && Numeric === rhs
    return  1 if Numeric === lhs && String  === rhs

    return lhs <=> rhs
  end

  return 0
end

required = Gem::Version.new('3.3.0') 
current = Gem::Version.new('3.3.0.dev')

comp(required,current)
#=> 1
```

Here the key is this line `return  1 if Numeric === lhs && String  === rhs`

Broken down as follows:

- lhsegments = [3,3]
- rhsegments = [3,3,"dev"]
- first 2 iterations result in `next if lhs == rhs`
- third iteration results in `return  1 if Numeric === lhs && String  === rhs` because `rhs` is a `String` and `lhs == 0` because `lhsegments[2] #=> nil`

You can find a "recommended approximation" using the following:

```
current.approximate_recommendation
#=> "~> 3.3.a"
new_required = Gem::Version.new('3.3.a') 
comp(new_required,required)
#=> -1 
comp(new_required,current) 
#=> -1
```

You can see using `'~> 3.3.a'` both '3.3.0.dev' or '3.3.0' will satisfy this requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the third one, it seems to me the best, but how can i avoid this if i only did was `rails new blog`, and it generates the wrong thing in the gem file?

Comment: @rubynt I cannot say other than to suggest you correct it in the Gemfile. It is likely that rails does not expect/want you to use pre-releases as valid ruby versions.